# Web Service Test Client with WSDL 2.0 + HTTP Support?

Tags: webservice-client, rest-client, wsdl-2.0

I am seeking an application or browser plugin with WSDL 2.0 service recognition and HTTP binding extension support, for the purpose of thorough web service testing.

I'm aware that XMLSpy has a [SOAP Client/Debugger](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/soap-client-debugger.html) with WSDL 2.0 support, but there is no support for HTTP bindings...

I'm not terribly interested in a discussion about WADL, or the evils of WSDL + REST.

A pipe dream for 2012, perhaps?

Comment: soapUI, maybe? I don't know if it has wsdl 2.0 support yet.